# Loading summary data with R similar to PROC FREQ

Tags: r, sas

I would like to know if anyone knows a way to load summary data weighted by count in R, like PROC FREQ in SAS does.

For instance loading data in SAS like this:

```
data q1;
input resid $ stress $ out $ count @@; datalines;
urban low fav 55 urban low unfav 34 
urban med fav 66 urban med unfav 64 
urban high fav 107 urban high unfav 89 
rural low fav 40 rural low unfav 25 
rural med fav 57 rural med unfav 47 
rural high fav 88 rural high unfav 60 
;
run;
```

allowing you to get a table of weighted data like via proc freq:

```
PROC FREQ data=q1;
weight count;
tables fav*urban;
run;
```

or run a logistic regression like:

```
Proc logistic data=q1;
    freq count;
    class stress(ref='low') resid(ref='urban')/ param=ref;
    model out(ref='unfav')=stress resid;
    run;
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, not every R users knows SAS so we don't exactly know what happens when you run those code in SAS. You should provide an example data along with expected output to show what you want to do.

Comment: It reads in the data with weights so that you you can consider weights the frequency. OP - search how to use weights in R but I haven't seen any easy replications for proc freq in R, ended up building our own internally.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr::uncount` you can do the following to answer the above

```
q1<-tibble(resid=c(rep(c("urban"),6),rep("rural",6)),
           stress=c(rep(c("low","low","med","med","high","high"),2)),
           out=c(rep(c("fav","unfav"),6)),
           n=c(55,34,66,64,107,89,40,25,57,47,88,60))
sum(q1$n)
q1_expanded<-tidyr::uncount(q1,n)
```

and you end up making a usable dataframe from summary data.